# How to manage the conditions of the increase of a score?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a problem with the program of my game Flappy Bird. I managed to increase a score on the screen. However, it increases every time the pipes come out of the screen, which is not what I want ...

Indeed, I would like the score to increase each time the bird passes between the pipes and so each time that tuyx and tuyx2 are equal to 67 but when I change the conditions, the score stays at 0.

Would anyone have the solution to my problem?
Here is the program and the pictures of my game ;)

[Here are the pictures](http://www.mediafire.com/file/nr1a1qmfsh6s8s4/Flappy+Bird.zip)

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from random import randint

def sauter(event):
    canvas.move(image_oiseau, 0, -10*DY)


def deplacement():
    global tuyx,tuyx2,h,H,oisx,oisy,solx,sol2x,score

    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.bbox(image_oiseau)
    if y1 < 416:
        canvas.move(image_oiseau, 0, DY)

    canvas.coords(image_sol,solx,512)  
    if solx >= -144:
        solx=solx-5
    else:
        solx=144

    canvas.coords(image_sol2,sol2x,512)
    if sol2x >= 144:
        sol2x=sol2x-5
    else:
        sol2x=432

    canvas.coords(image_tuyau_haut,tuyx,h)
    canvas.coords(image_tuyau_bas,tuyx,h-241)
    if tuyx>=-28:
        tuyx=tuyx-5
    else:
        tuyx=316
        h=randint(256,505)
        score+=1

    canvas.coords(image_tuyau_haut2,tuyx2,H)
    canvas.coords(image_tuyau_bas2,tuyx2,H-241)
    if tuyx2>=-28:
        tuyx2=tuyx2-5
    else:
        tuyx2=316
        H=randint(256,505)
        score+=1

    lscore.config(text=str(score))    
    canvas.after(40,deplacement)  

LARGEUR = 286
HAUTEUR = 510
DY = 5
tuyx=316
tuyx2=488 
h=randint(256,505)
H=randint(256,505)
oisx=67
oisy=244
solx=144
sol2x=432
score=0


fenetre = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(fenetre, width=LARGEUR, height=HAUTEUR)

fond = PhotoImage(file="background-day.png")
fond2 = PhotoImage(file="background-night.png")
fond=[fond,fond2]
F= random.choice(fond)
canvas.create_image(144,256, anchor=CENTER,image=F)

tuyau_haut = PhotoImage(file="tuyau_vers_le_haut.png")
image_tuyau_haut = canvas.create_image(tuyx,h,anchor=CENTER,image=tuyau_haut)
image_tuyau_haut2 = canvas.create_image(tuyx2,H,anchor=CENTER,image=tuyau_haut)

tuyau_bas = PhotoImage(file="tuyau_vers_le_bas.png")
image_tuyau_bas = canvas.create_image(tuyx,h,anchor=CENTER,image=tuyau_bas)
image_tuyau_bas2 = canvas.create_image(tuyx2,H,anchor=CENTER,image=tuyau_bas)

sol = PhotoImage(file="sol-day.png")
image_sol = canvas.create_image(144,512, anchor=S,image=sol)
image_sol2 = canvas.create_image(432,512, anchor=S,image=sol)

oiseau = PhotoImage(file="yellowbird-midflap.png")
oiseau2 = PhotoImage(file="bluebird-midflap.png")
oiseau3 = PhotoImage(file="redbird-midflap.png")
oiseau=[oiseau,oiseau2,oiseau3]
O=random.choice(oiseau)
image_oiseau=canvas.create_image(oisx,oisy, anchor=W,image=O) 

lscore=Label(fenetre,text='0')
lscore.pack()

deplacement()

canvas.pack()
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind("<space>",sauter) 

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add your pictures in the question instead of providing external link.

Comment: I thought it was better as a solution.
Indeed, there are about 7 images, that's a lot, that's why I gave the link to download all the images in a .zip file :)